# Unable to view vote counts in review lists

Tags: feature-request, review, privileges

While going through the review (first posts) lists I noticed that I was unable to directly view the vote count from that interface.

Obviously it is pretty easy to just open the post in a new tab and see that information (and anyone that can view the review queues already has that [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)), so I was wondering if this is a bug or if it by-design?

(I wanted to check since there was a comment about the votes on that post.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is intentional (and that this question is a duplicate), but I am unable to find anything yet to back that up.

Comment: I thought I might have read something similar here on meta, but I was unable to find anything.

Comment: Closest I've managed to find so far is a bug report for this same issue under the old review system. That was changed, though, to allow viewing vote counts.

Comment: Judging by @David edit, this is indeed by design..