# Loss of privilege on the review page

Tags: support, voting, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to view vote counts in review lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148744/unable-to-view-vote-counts-in-review-lists)

I started my reviewing journey yesterday, and today I came across a "first post" review of a question with 3 votes. The user had under 20 points, so I thought to check the up/down votes.

**WHAM** I got whacked by the sense of loss, when my super powers of vote peeking stopped working. It made me sad :(

Can this be rectified?

I found some other questions about the design of the new-ish (time of writing) review page, but didn't see one specifically about the votes.

Comment: I hate when WHAM happens, too, especially when loss of super powers are involved.  Really leaves you hanging.